# Can I change the default path of databases using commands in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

In SQL Server 2008 I can indicate the path where I want to store the database in the query, when I am creating the database. Can I do the same in MySQL with a query?
In SQL Server is something like this:

```
create database myDatabase
on primary
(
name=myDatabase_DATA,
Filename='a path in C:\ with mdf extension',
Maxsize=10MB,
FileGrowth=10%
)
log on
(
name=myDatabase_LOG,
Filename='a path in C:\ with ldf extension',
Maxsize=10MB,
FileGrowth=10%
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can I do the same in MySQL with a query?

No. In MySQL that needs to be done in server configuration files.

Here's some information, in case you choose to take this path.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-data-directories.html